# C++ textbox contents

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

How do I get the contents of a textbox in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Win32 API [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx) passing in the text box's window handle.

If you want to get the text from another process use [WM_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627(v=VS.85).aspx) instead with [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: If in the string I had "1 + 1", do you know how I could make it do 1 + 1?

Comment: @ITg: You will probably need to parse the string into parts and then do your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

[CWnd::GetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db50wx7h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

GetWindowText()

Answer (score 1):

Correction to last post:

```
//unicode std::string or std::wstring
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> unicode_string;

unicode_string GetWinString(HWND h)
{
int len = ::GetWindowTextLength(h);
if (len)
  {
  std::vector<TCHAR> tmp(len + 1,_T('\0'));
  ::GetWindowText(h,&tmp[0],len + 1);
  return &tmp[0];
  }
return _T("");
}
```

Comment: There's an "edit" option below your posts; please don't post additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
//unicode std::string or std::wstring
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> unicode_string;

unicode_string GetWinString(HWND h)
{
int len = ::GetWindowTextLength(h);
if (len)
  {
  std::vector<TCHAR> tmp(len + 1,_T('\0'));
  ::GetWindowText(h,&tmp[0],len + 1);
  return &tmp[0];
  }
return _T("");
}
```